# Nadex Trading Bot

Tags: python, selenium, automation, scrapy, trading

I understand that someone else has posed a similar question about creating a nadex bot but the answers seemed scarce.  I would like to create an Nadex auto trading bot but they do not provide an api.  I can get the price for the actual future quickly from other sources but I need to be able to get the price of the contracts relatively quickly and place trades automatically on the site.  I was thinking about using selenium or scrappy but I'm uncertain about how to POST to the website to place trades.  Any guidance or direction would be appreciated.
**I understand the risks of the program breaking and losing money, this is more of a test project**

Comment: selenium is just browser automation. If Nadex has a page where you enter the ticker symbol, amount, and click the trade button you just instruct selenium to do that - selenium doesn't care about get vs post or anything like that.

Comment: I understand that selenium is just browser automation but I'm concerned as to how quickly selenium can perform an action, it would need to fill in one two texts field and click two buttons as quickly as possible

Comment: it will do that as quickly as possible but the possible speed will depend on your machine, internet connection, and the site's performance. I'm not sure what your question really is. The browser will be slower than using your own http client to make post requests. Phantomjs will be faster than chromedriver since it's headless. Additionally I'm sure it's against their terms of service to scrape their site so they may block you if you send requests too quickly.